# How to override the "form_div_layout" base template?

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I want to override the base tempale to be used in twig.

I have used this

```
twig:
    form:
        resources:
            - 'form_div_layout.html.twig'
```

and I have copied the file from original location to 
`app/resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig` but still I am not able to see the changes in template rendering.

Basically I just want to add the class in DIV box generated

```
{% block form_widget_compound %}
{% spaceless %}
    <div class="MYCLASS" 
    {{ block('widget_container_attributes') }}>
        {% if form.parent is empty %}
            {{ form_errors(form) }}
        {% endif %}
        {{ block('form_rows') }}
        {{ form_rest(form) }}
    </div>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock form_widget_compound %}
```

Do I need to make any more change ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don´t need to copy the full file if you just want to customize one field. Do this:

If you just want to do this for just one template, add this to your template:

```
{% form_theme form _self %}

{% block form_widget_compound %}
{% spaceless %}
    <div class="MYCLASS" >
    {{ block('widget_container_attributes') }}>
        {% if form.parent is empty %}
            {{ form_errors(form) }}
        {% endif %}
        {{ block('form_rows') }}
        {{ form_rest(form) }}
    </div>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock form_widget_compound %}
```

If you want to customize this in several templates, do this: create a template file in your bundle with this code:

```
{# src/Acme/DemoBundle/Resources/views/Form/fields.html.twig #}
{% block form_widget_compound %}
{% spaceless %}
    <div class="MYCLASS" >
    {{ block('widget_container_attributes') }}>
        {% if form.parent is empty %}
            {{ form_errors(form) }}
        {% endif %}
        {{ block('form_rows') }}
        {{ form_rest(form) }}
    </div>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock form_widget_compound %}
```

Then in those templates where you want to use this customized field, do:

```
{% form_theme form 'AcmeDemoBundle:Form:fields.html.twig' %}
```

If you want this customization to be available in ALL templates of a bundle, add this to your config file:

```
# app/config/config.yml
twig:
    form:
        resources:
            - 'AcmeDemoBundle:Form:fields.html.twig'
```

If you want this to be available for ALL bundles, copy this file to

```
app/Resources/AcmeDemoBundle/views/Form/fields.html.twig
```

Comment: I want to do this for all the templates in all bundles. Is there any way that i don't need to change individual templates

Comment: I created a template according to bootstrap setup. It includes the label_attr class, to set it to control-label. Now, i would like to have a few rows with a help tooltip, so I need to add a class. The formbuilder doesn't override the template. So, is it possible to define a custom row, e.g. a block form_row_custom, and then have the formbuilder use this one?

Answer (score 1):

To do what you are trying copy just **form_div_layout.html.twig** in resources without the **Form** folder and then in config reffer to it this way: **::form_div_layout.html.twig**

```
twig:
    form:
        resources:
            - '::form_div_layout.html.twig'
```

You don't have to copy all of it. You can extend only parts of it..

Answer (score 0):

Here it is, plain and simple. To override only certain blocks **application-wide** you *must* use a different file name than `form_div_layout.html.twig` otherwise you will get errors. If you copy the entire file and make changes, this isn't a problem. But if you only want to override some of the blocks, this is how you do it:

Create the file `app/Resources/views/forms.html.twig` and paste in the blocks you want to customize. The filename isn't important as long as it is *not* `form_div_layout.html.twig`.

Next add this to the twig configuration in `app/config/config.yml`

```
# app/config/config.yml
twig:
    form:
        resources: ["::forms.html.twig"]
```

Answer (score 0):

To make full **global** override of original *form_div_layout.html.twig* template but NOT copy entire file do next

Theory:

1. Add twig load **path** for original file (to avoid requrssion)
2. Optional. Add explicit form_themes
3. Place in your default path new 'form_div_layout.html.twig'
4. extend in the new file from the original by [path] namescpace

So. Practice

In your symfony twig config place it:

```yaml
# symfony/config/packages/twig.yaml
twig:
    default_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/templates'
    # 1 step
    paths:
        - value: '%kernel.project_dir%/../vendor/symfony/twig-bridge/Resources/views/Form/'
          namespace: 'TwigBridge'

    form_themes:
        - '@SonataForm/Form/datepicker.html.twig'
        # 2nd
        - 'form_div_layout.html.twig'
```

Create new file **symfony dir**/*templates/form_div_layout.html.twig*

```
# '%kernel.project_dir%/templates'
# OR
# templates/form_div_layout.html.twig*
{#{% extends 'vendor/symfony/twig-bridge/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig' %}#}
{% extends '@TwigBridge/form_div_layout.html.twig' %}

# make override - replace original form widget
{%- block dateinterval_widget -%}
  {{ parent() }}
{%- endblock dateinterval_widget -%}
```

To make local overrides see other answers.